# How to create Segmented control with underline in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

How to create Segmented control with underline in iOS (like on image on the left)?

As far as I understood it's similar to Android native control.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can help you solve the problem.

Comment: I had to do the very same thing some time ago.  I created a custom UIControl in swift to handle it.  Here's the repo: https://github.com/johnrufusj/customSwiftControls/blob/master/UnderlineSegmentedControl.swift

Answer (score 1):

`UISegmentedControl` includes API for customizing it's appearance. You set images for various state combinations using `-setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` and `-setDividerImage:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:barMetrics:`.

You can also customize the text using `-setTitleTextAttributes:forState:`.

These methods can be found in the [Customizing Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW33) section of the `UISegmentedControl` documentation.

Comment: does this approach always use antialiasing ?