# IOS UI Segmented Controls with an underline

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering how do you do make a underline in ios segmented controls text.

Thanks

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

Comment: there's a pod for it: https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO post may help you [How to create Segmented control with underline in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559300/how-to-create-segmented-control-with-underline-in-ios).
You may be able to do it by using attributes. Something like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"yourtext"
                                                                      attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)}]];
[_segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributedString  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```